# Split a string that includes Korean characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a string containing Korean characters:

```
s = '굿모닝, today is 촉촉'
```

I want to split it as:

```
t = ['굿모닝', 'today', 'is', '촉촉']
```

Note that all the Korean characters are put together instead of separated, that is, it is '굿모닝', not '굿', '모', '닝'.

**Questions:**

- How do I split that string to get the required output?
- Do I need to use a regular expression?

Comment: `s.split(" ")`?

Comment: What you want can be achieved by `s.split()`. Can you describe a more complex example or how you want to split by regex?

Comment: Sorry that I am not familiar with regular expression. I searched the web that I may use re.findall and somethings like [\u3131-\ucb4c], but I don't know to do that exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Korean has any relevance here... The only issue I can think of is that pesky comma right after the first 3 characters which prevents you from using straight `s.split()` but [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) are mighty!!

```
import re
s = '굿모닝, Today is 촉촉'
re.split(',?\s', s)
```

Outputs `['굿모닝', 'Today', 'is', '촉촉']`

Just split your string by an optional comma `,?` followed by a non-optional white character `\s`

Comment: Thank you very much, BorrajaX.

Comment: No problem!! **:-)**

Comment: What about the more complicated string containing Korean, Chinese and English? S = '굿모닝, Today is 촉촉. 小心保重'. How to obtain the result of ['굿모닝', 'Today', 'is', '촉촉', '小', '心', '保', '重']?

Comment: Oh, that's a different ballgame... Not because of the Chinese characters per se, but because there's no clear *divider*. I mean... You want to get `촉촉` together but `小`, `心`, `'保` and `重` separately... It's very difficult to tell that to a regular expression (as a matter of fact, I don't know how to do it)

Comment: You might wanna take a look to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3797746/289011) (particularly the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3797753/289011) that talks about NLP)