# How to search for the longest word in the string

Tags: ruby

```
  def my_inject(*args)
    return yield false if args.empty? && !block_given?

    case args.length
    when 1 then args.first.is_a?(Symbol) ? sym = args.first : result = args.first
    when 2 then result = args.first
                sym = args.last
    end


    result ||= 0
    my_each { |x| result = block_given? ? yield(result, x) : result.send(sym, x) }

    result
  end
```

What can I add to this code to make it search for the longest word in Array of strings and were add it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string.split(" ")
      .max_by(&:length)
```

See [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

Comment: Just for fun, I'll point out that some natural languages don't separate words with spaces. Check out questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797746/how-to-do-a-python-split-on-languages-like-chinese-that-dont-use-whitespace if you're curious. :)

Answer (score 1):

> What can I add to this code to make it search for the longest word in a string

```
"this is a test of the emergency broadcast system".split(' ').sort {|x,y| y.length <=> x.length}.first
```

To break this down we:

- assign a sentence as a string
- split that string into words
- sort each word by comparing its length with the previous word's length
- take the first result

More information on sorting in Ruby at https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Enumerable/sort

Comment: I am sorry for this stupid question first not a string it's Array of strings and where to add it ? because it's not working

Comment: Hi @Sanad, can you provide example. Whether you are trying to get the max string from an array of string like ` ['abc' , 'abcd', 'abcdef']` or its just a string like `'this is a string'`
if its an array you can probably use `arr.max_by(&:length)` or if its a string you can probably use `str.split(' ').max_by(&:length)`

Answer (score 0):

Some assumptions:

1. Each array item only contains one word
2. You only want the longest word returned, not the position

```rb
words = %w[tiny humungous antidisestablishmentarianism medium]

puts words.max_by(&:length)
```